# in Rbbg how can I check if connection is broken

Tags: r, rjava

Using the `Rbbg` package, I use `conn<-blpConnect()` to connect to Bloomberg, but frequently the connection gets broken with the following error (even if Bloomberg is logged in, and BBComm is running):

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session Not Started
```

One alternative is to write a `tryCatch` statement that will run `blpConnect` every time a connection breaks, but that doesn't seem to be very efficient. Is there a way in R (or in `rJava`) to test if the connection `conn` is still valid?

For instance, in MATLAB, there is a function `isconnection` to test if the connection `conn` is still valid, and we can write an `if` line to reconnect.